# How to fix encoding problem when convert XML to JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, xml

I have an xml file. I need to convert xml file to json format and write it in html with node js.

XML file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
<ROWDATA>

<ROW>
  <REG1_CODE>02</REG1_CODE>
  <REG1>Вінницька обл.</REG1>
  <REG2_CODE>19</REG2_CODE>
  <REG2>Тиврівський р-н</REG2>
  <REG3_CODE>001</REG3_CODE>
  <REG3>с. Борсків</REG3>
</ROW>
</ROWDATA>
```

My code to convert xml to json

```
const fs = require('fs')
const xml2js = require('xml2js')
const parser = new xml2js.Parser()
const http = require('http')
const util = require('util')

function onRequest(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain;'});
    fs.readFile('regions.xml', null, function (error, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
            if (error) {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Bla bla');
            } else {
                response.write(util.inspect(result, false, null, true))

            }
            response.end();
        })
    })
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000)
```

This code output.

```
{
  ROWDATA: {
    ROW: [
      {
        REG1_CODE: [ [32m'02'[39m ],
        REG1: [ [32m'ВіпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅ.'[39m ],
        REG2_CODE: [ [32m'19'[39m ],
        REG2: [ [32m'пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅ-пїЅ'[39m ],
        REG3_CODE: [ [32m'001'[39m ],
        REG3: [ [32m'пїЅ. пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ'[39m ]
      },
}
```

How to fix this encoding problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try do `fs.readFile(filepath, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {})` ?

The other options are documented here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback